# Two textviews switch from foreground to background and back

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a view with two textviews in it. By touching on the first textview i resize it to "fullscreen" an it works fine, but touching ob the second textview the part where the first textview is is behind the first textview.
Is there any possibility to set to change overlap properties ob the textviews?

Answer (score 1):

-[UIView bringSubviewToFront:]
-[UIView sendSubviewToBack:]